# CSS: Why this code can't float to the right?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create this set of social icon to float to the right and I'm having a problem to make it.

If I float it to the left it works fine, but I can't change to the right.

- http://jsfiddle.net/retse/1/

I don't know if I missed anything that it doesn't make it float to the right?

EDIT: I'm going to update with part of the HTML code where I have a problem in a minute.

http://applesiam.com the class name is correct and I've css name there in my page but still it doesn't float to the right

Sorry about that.

Comment: An example on http://jsfiddle.net/ would help.

Comment: How can we help if we don't know the markup? Your CSS rule looks fine (syntactically). That does not mean that it is what you need or that it is sufficient. To be able to help, we need more information.

Comment: Updated with http://jsfiddle.net/retse/1/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your jsfiddle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/retse/2/)

you've had wrong class names there

Comment: Sorry I've updated it too now I'm confuse what is wrong since in jsfiddle is correct but in my page it doesn't work.

http://applesiam.com I've the class name correct there.

Comment: @Ali: in which of the 8 stylesheets on your website do you have the rule that floats `.post-widget1` to the right? According to Chrome’s web inspector, `.post-widget1` doesn’t have any styles applied to it at all.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite it's in style.css

Comment: @Ali: I searched http://applesiam.com/wp-content/themes/Backstreet/style.css for `post-widget1`, and got no results.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Same here I'm very confused now why I can't see them while I saved it and I reopen and still I can see it from the ftp. Also I can see them using Terminal login with `root` account and permission is setted to `apache` which is default

Comment: @Ali: perhaps the old version of the stylesheet is cached somewhere. I’d suggest accepting one of the answers on this question (as they were correct with the information given at the time), then asking another question — possibly on [the Wordpress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) — about why the stylesheets for your Wordpress site aren’t updating.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thanks I will try see what can I do first and if I can't I will post and ask over there Thanks for the helP!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any classes named share1 and/or widget1, they're named post-share1 and post-widget1.